# how to use type="color" in <button> tag

Tags: html, button, colors, twitter-bootstrap-4

I need to use a button tag with a color picker , but I can't use input because the value can't be a google material icon
what can I do?

```
<button type="color" value="#ff0000" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary herramienta"><i class="material-icons">format_color_text</i></button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably have an input with opacity set to 0, put it on top of the button, and then when they go to click the button, they actually click on the input, something like:

```
<div style="position:relative; display:inline-block">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary herramienta"><i class="material-icons">format_color_text</i></button>
    <input type="color" value="#ff0000" style="opacity:0; position:absolute; left:0;top:0;width:100%"/>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3u8v5axs/